# Javafx Datepicker validation

Tags: datepicker, javafx-8

we tried to validate a javafx datepicker. So we use:

```
if (fromDatePicker.getValue() == null) {
        sb.append("No valid from date!\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println(fromDatePicker.getValue().toString());
        if (!DateUtil
                .validEnglishDate(fromDatePicker.getValue().toString())) {
            sb.append("No valid from date. Use the format yyyy-MM-dd.\n");
        }
    }
```

But at the moment it's impossible to get an invalid Date with the datepicker, because all invalid date's are changed to the start value. 
So we asked us is it possible to get an invalid Date with the javafx datepicker?

***** EDIT *****

Example: we have the following datepicker:
DatePicker[2015-05-12]
now we entered "fjdfk" in the DatePicker so we have:
DatePicker[fjdfk]
on save the data's the datepicker changes automatical to DatePicker[2015-05-12]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by an "invalid Date"? `DatePicker.getValue()` will either return `null`, or an actual [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instance. If it's not null, [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) will format it in a particular way (the javadocs tell you the format). You can always format the result differently with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) if you need.

Comment: I have the same use case. `DatePicker.getValue()` does not return `null`; it returns the previous value. Is there any way to intercept the DatePicker validation (perhaps with a property listener)? I want to display a message to the user, such as "Please enter a valid date".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `DatePicker#setConverter(StringConverter<LocalDate>)` to catch any parse exception and warn the user in consequence. Here is a sample :

```
public class SecureLocalDateStringConverter extends StringConverter<LocalDate> {
    /**
     * The date pattern that is used for conversion. Change as you wish.
     */
    private static final String DATE_PATTERN = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    /**
    * The date formatter.
    */
    public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN);

    private boolean hasParseError = false;

    public boolean hasParseError(){
        return hasParseError;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(LocalDate localDate) {
       return DATE_FORMATTER.format(localDate);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate fromString(String formattedString) {

            try {
                LocalDate date=LocalDate.from(DATE_FORMATTER.parse(formattedString));
                hasParseError=false;
                return date;
            } catch (DateTimeParseException parseExc){
                hasParseError=true;
                return null;
            }
    }

}
```

From your control, you'll just have to call `converter#hasParseError()`, `converter` being the one you set with `DatePicker#setConverter(StringConverter<LocalDate>)`