# JavaFX - TextField input validation of multiple statements

Tags: java, validation, input, javafx, textfield

I'm trying to figure out, how to do input validation of text field/s when I need for example a date input. It needs to be in format like 31.8.2016 and it has to be today's date or later. So that's two different checks.

Only way I can think off is creating boolean method which will check whether the date is past or future. But I would need to create a new method to check if it's in the right format which will be harder but I think this is not the right approach.

Comment: may this one help you => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432576/javafx-datepicker-validation

Comment: Why I don't have Date Picker tag in my Scene Builder library?

Comment: Which version of SceneBuilder do you have?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.. I had 1.1.. I already have Scene Builder 2.0, it's fine now thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a date class which looks like this:

public class Date{

```
    private boolean validDay = false;
    private boolean validMonth = false;
    private boolean validYear = false;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Date(int day, int month, int year){
        /*
         *All of these conditions can also be individually used to check the conditions you 
         *want to check. simply create 3 texfields and put them in a HBox all values must be entered
         *separately !
         */
        if(day>=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && day<=cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
            this.day = day;
            this.validDay = true;
        }
        else{
            //TODO: handle
        }
        if(month>=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) && month<=12){
            this.month = month;
            this.validMonth= true;
        }
        else{
            //TODO: handle
        }
        if(year>=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
            this.year = year;
            this.validYear = true;
        }
        else{
            //TODO: handle
        }
    }
    public boolean isDateValid(){
        return validDay && validMonth && validYear;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return day+"."+month+"."+year;
    }
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
}
```

you could split the input with a String splitter and crate date!
you could also add set methods!
there are many ways to do this!
I hope this helps!